# Swing components re sizing according to resolution

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager

I have created a complex GUI using Netbeans GUI builder. My working PC has a higher resolution and in that machine it is shown as needed. But when I check the program in another computer with lower resolution everything is placed correctly but has becomes large and so some components can't be seen(I don't want to use scroll bars).

So how can I make the GUI appear the same in all the resolutions (at least for full HD and 1366x768)?

Comment: Use layout managers and manually create your GUI.

Comment: You can't control the resolution people use on their computers so you need to design the application to take this into account by 1) not trying to fit too many components at the larger resolution, (which means you have to design for the smaller resolution or 2) Using scrollpanes to allow the user to see all components when the components don't fit on the smaller resolution.

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Make sure you call `.pack()` on your top level components, that should lay them out so everything fits.  Do not try to set the size of anything manually.  If `.pack()` doesn't work try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem and post it here.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will get the screen size for different resolutions.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

If you want effective screen size i.e. a screen size without taskbar.

```
Rectangle rectangle = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

Comment: While this *might* (but probably won't) be useful for part of the final strategy, it does not attempt to answer the core of the question.

Comment: `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`  Also note that the `screenSize` will not account for the size of the task bar, and is thereby not the same as the **usable** screen size..